# Dropdown not expanding due to element below it in MVC Razor view

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have created a dropdown inside a view with following code..

```
<div class="form-group col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        Ask
        <select name="drpExpertId" id="drp_ExpertId" class="dropdown">
            <option value="0">-- Select Expert --</option>
            @foreach (var item in Model.ExpertsList)
            {
                <option value="@item.Id">@item.ExpertName, the @item.ExpertArea</option>
            }
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">&nbsp;</div>

    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.ExpertComment.Question, new { @class = "form-control ", placeholder = "Your Question" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ExpertComment.QuestionAskedDate, new { @Value = DateTime.UtcNow })
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default text-danger" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        &nbsp;
    </div>
</div>
```

value in dropdown is coming properly when I see it by inspecting it. but in UI it doesn't expend. when I put line break (<br/><br/><br/>) after the div of dropdown, it starts showing values and it also expands.
i am not able to find out what mistake I am doing.
Above mentioned part of the code comes under @Html.BeginForm and have class

```
new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" })
```

There is no other class or CSS applied in this code.

Comment: This is off-topic from your question, but since you are using razor, why don't you use an HTML Helper method like `@Html.DropDownListFor`?

Comment: You should find a way to show an example of what's going wrong. Maybe copy the generated HTML and put it into a jsfiddle or something to show us what you mean.

Comment: I'm guessing it's something to do with Bootstrap, which you appear to be using, rather than anything else. You may want to update your question and tags to reflect that you're using that framework if you are.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I am using bootstrap but I also tried by removing all the classes. I am using same classes at other place for dropdown in the same application and those are working fine. :(

Comment: I think @i7nvd's advice is the right one. Right now, someone would have to try and recreate everything in your ASP.NET MVC app, which is asking a lot of volunteers. Instead, try to create a [mcve] so that others can reproduce.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan you were right, due to bootstrap an unwanted css position: relative; was getting added and it was creating all the problem. earlier I had removed all the classes but by mistake one was left.

Answer (score 0):

Now the changed code is..

```
<div>
        Ask
        <select name="drpExpertId" id="drp_ExpertId">
            <option value="0">-- Select Expert --</option>
            @foreach (var item in Model.ExpertsList)
            {
                <option value="@item.Id">@item.ExpertName, the @item.ExpertArea</option>
            }
        </select>
    </div>
```

This is working fine.